# "C:\Program Files" on Windows Vista+ (x64)

Tags: windows

Exactly what is the difference between:

> C:\Program Files
>   C:\Program Files (x86)
>   C:\ProgramData

I have two questions:

1. Why are they different?
2. How do I decide which one to look in for any given resource, to avoid having to look in them all and merge the information in my head?

Answer (score 7):

#### Briefly

`Program Files` is where 64bit software is installed.

`Program Files (x86)` is where 32bit software is installed.

`Program Data` is where both sets of programs should write data (such as configuration data, for example) that they want to store for all users (so can't go in a single users `AppData` or `MyDocs`) and that does not belong in registry.

---

The difference between the two `ProgFiles` folders allows you to have two different versions of software installed (for example Internet Explorer comes in both 32 and 64 bit flavors installed together) because Windows silently redirects requests from software in the `(x86)` folders.

---

As for question 2, you can probably ignore `Program Data` most of the time (nothing should be *installed* in there), but I often find myself jumping between the two `ProgFiles` folders so I'll be looking for other answers here to help with that.

Comment: Is there any reason why 64-bit software and 32-bit software had to be split in this way?  I mean, it's just files on the disk, isn't it?

Comment: No idea! I've *heard* it's for compatability reasons. But all my 32bit and 64bit games (not many in the latter category) are installed in `C:\Games` and I have not problems with either. Plus I've loads of utilities I run straight off my `D:`.

Comment: [This](http://serverfault.com/questions/8763/program-files-vs-program-files-x86-in-64-bit-windows) question on ServerFault might be useful. I'll add some of the key points to my answer.

Comment: It's important for some programs! Some compilers, Integrated Development Environments and similar programs have need for both 32bit version and 64 bit version. It's not uncommon to find 64 bit in Program Files and 32 in Program Files (x86). Still, there is no need for directories o be called like that. They may as well be called a and b. It's just that x86 hints at its contents.

Comment: Note however that some programs can have "C:\Program Files\" has their default path, directly written, without caring about the appropriate folder. That's how you end with 32-bit programs in the folder in theory dedicated to 64-bit.

Comment: Indeed, those that don't use the `%ProgramFiles%` environment variable cannot be automagically redirected by Windows.

Comment: This blog post gives quite good explanation of the various 16/32/64-bit folders: 
http://piers7.blogspot.com/2010/07/64-bit-explained.html

Comment: @DMA57361, @Gnoupi: It is theoretically possible, though, as Windows 64-bit already redirects 32-bit applications writing to `C:\Windows\System32` into `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`.

Comment: @Hello, @Mario's answer has the link to [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd765197%28VS.85%29.aspx) which indicates redirects are done assuming programs call a specific API function to get the relevant folder. If a program has it's path hard-coded in then it won't get redirected.

Comment: @DMA57361: I opened a 32-bit Command Prompt, `cd`ed to `C:\Windows\System32`, then wrote a file. Then, I used 64-bit Windows Explorer to navigate to `C:\Windows\System32`. The file wasn't there. I then navigated to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`. The file was in there. Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit.

Comment: @Hello Same here. Very interesting, but we can't rely on the behaviour of elements provided as part of the OS to work the same as a "normal" program, there *might* be additional magic in them to ensure compatibility. What we really need to is to build a simple program that simply checks for a file in `system32` (that doesn't appear in `syswow64`, possible created), compile to both 32 and 64 bits versions, and then see what happens.

Comment: @Hello, well it seems you are correct. I made a `txt` file in `system32` and built a quick C++ app to read out it to console (using `C:/windows/system32` hardcoded). Compiled as 32bit it did not find the file, compiled 64bit and it does.

Answer (score 4):

Like @DMA57361 said, on Windows Vista x64, **Program Files** is where x64 software is installed, and **Program Files (x86)** is where x86 software is installed.

Windows (x64 versions) categorizes software this way due to a feature (for the [Windows Installer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer) ***Installation Cotext***) called ***“[Folder redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd765197(VS.85).aspx)”***. Windows (x64 versions) have this feature probably beacause that's the way they can still support and categorize x86 applications.

About the second question, the "**C:\ProgramData**" is a folder that stores user related information
that is shared by all accounts.

Comment: Good link. I've run out of votes for today, but I'll try to remember to come back and give you a +1 tomorrow!