# Change the installation directory of windows-store-apps on windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-store-app

How could I change the default installation directory of windows-apps in windows 8.1 ?

It was possible in windows 8.0 (see [here](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/change-default-install-location-windows-8-store-apps)) but it doesn't work for 8.1.

(I currently have two hard disk and I would like that apps go to the second one)

Comment: The solution still Windows 8.0 actually does work in 8.1 I am not aware of any other method.  At the end of the day the method itself is not actually supported by Microsoft.

Comment: Related: [Forcing programs to be installed to another drive](http://superuser.com/questions/755465/forcing-programs-to-be-installed-to-another-drive/755511#755511)