# Boost Up My Old Laptop Using a SSD

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, laptop, ssd

I have an old laptop **Lenovo SL400** (Core2Duo T9550 2.66GHz / 4GB DDR2 RAM).

Since I can't afford to buy a new laptop, I thought maybe I could throw an ADATA SP600 64GB SSD as primary drive and move my current HDD to DVD-ROM space by using HDDCADDY. I know that 64 GB will come short after installing Visual Studio, SQL Server, etc. So is there anyway to just install the  kernel part of windows on SSD and the rest on HDD.

Doesn't Windows have built-in support to do this? (ReadyBoost is out of picture since it's just simple caching)

**EDIT:**
To clarify more, note that I'm worried if I buy these tools, my system drive (being the SSD here) may come short at some point. Plus, if there was a smart caching technique like `Intel's Smart Response technology` (which of course my old laptop doesn't support) I could even buy a `32 GB SSD` and pay less for this update.

Comment: the kernel is probably always in RAM.

Comment: You can move all of program Files and user directories into another drive, which is what I've done in the past given a similar situation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Forcing programs to be installed to another drive](http://superuser.com/questions/755465/forcing-programs-to-be-installed-to-another-drive)

Comment: Wait, wait. **What actual problem** are you trying to solve? Is the system running slow? Do you have too much space on the system drive? Or what? If you [edit] your question and tell us what specific problem you are trying to solve, we'll be much more likely to be able to come up with an answer that addresses that problem.

Comment: @OMGtechy No my problem isn't that. I always install huge installations on a separate drive (D) but still there are some system files installed on main drive(C:) and after a few huge isntallations (MATLAB, Visual Studio, etc) my C fills up pretty much (up to 54GB). I thought Windows could handle moving repetitive file requests to the SSD automatically. If I could by a 128GB SSD I woudln't have any problem but my hands are tied here...

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: please see the above comment :)

Comment: @and31415: it's a good idea bu I think it would mess with Microsoft's proprietary softwares like Visual Studio Team Foundation and etc.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in an above comment, your best solution is to install the SSD into your laptop, install windows. (This will be your boot drive, C drive etc)

Then connect your second hdd, then when you install your software, select the hdd as the install directory, you can install software on a separate drive from your C drive.

This should be a reasonable solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks, but as I've mentioned above, after some huge installation even on other drives, lots of space from main drive is still used (54GB)... I've even installed apps like Notepad++ to other drive than C:

Comment: Ah I see, I hope you get the answer you need!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your idea will improve your system performance. Windows is not using disk much, especially if you have enough RAM. Hard disk is used mostly by complicated programs (like photo editing software, video editing software, games. You should install these on fast device.

If you have not enough RAM - pagefile is used (like swap in Linux) to extend available memory and that may make difference. By default pagefile is on C:\, but can be moved on other disk.

Windows kernel is pretty small and it is loaded just once into memory and you don't have to have it on fast storage device.

In my opinion - you should put your .NET libraries on SSD, I think they have highest "load" when system is running. .NET files are here: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET`.

However thats just my guess, you could investigate this better with some disk tool that shows what files are used frequently on your computer.

**You can mount storage device to folder in Windows.**

[Assign a mount point folder path to a drive](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753321.aspx)

BUT folder must be empty. So if you want to store C:\Users on separate partition/volume/disk - that will be complicated. You have to do it in command line safe mode. I was using separate device for "C:\Documents and settings\" like this in windows XP many times. Im not sure if you can do that for .NET directories, but it may. I recommend to do things like this on fresh system or after full backup, if you are not experienced - you can break your system.

Another method - before installing Windows you can change standard directories locations (like Program Files, System, Users) with System Preparation Tools (sysprep.exe) but I would... just buy bigger SSD disk.

Comment: Thanks Kamil, I've turned off my virtual memory (swap) in order to keep my data in ram and achieve a faster speed. I was hoping for a low (near hardware) level technology to do this. But I think I have to go with moving the system folders...