# Does changing an application's target directory after installation also require changing registry keys

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry

We have an application based on CTI, in which we have changed some DLL files and kept the application target directory (the changed one) in D:.

However, the old application installation directory is in C:\Program Files

Will using the application which is on the D:\ drive have any impact or cause slowness as the registry keys are pointing to the C:\ drive?

Do I need to change the registry keys as well?

Comment: Maybe this link could help you. https://superuser.com/questions/1018484/can-i-move-installed-programs-to-another-location-in-windows

Comment: @OOOO hey,thanks for the link, I don't want to disturb original folder, my question is is there any impact using application from different location