# All program files on a different drive

Tags: windows

Is it possible to put the **entire** Program Files/Program Files (x86) folder to a different location. Not just change it in the registry so the default installation folder is different. But even things like Windows Defender?

This would make it so **only** the windows and the users folder would be on the main hardrive/partition.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Google 'symlink'

Comment: possible duplicate of [Forcing programs to be installed to another drive](http://superuser.com/questions/755465/forcing-programs-to-be-installed-to-another-drive), [How can I change the default program installation directory in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/185414/how-can-i-change-the-default-program-installation-directory-in-windows-7)

Comment: That amount of hoop-jumping to perform a simple task makes me glad I don't use windows :P

Comment: @Tetsujin I would love to switch over to some Unix based system. Although not all the applications I need are compatible.

Comment: you can do symbolic linking on win - maybe this may help, but i'm no expert on it... http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/ [Techie, on the other hand, I would listen to, based on my perception of his/her knowledge]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that on multi different ways, the easiest way is to use a third party tool, or use the `mklink` command (safest and best way to do it).

`mklink` will create symbolic links to the current location, and forward it to the new location. What that means, If you move the Program files from C to X and made symbolic link to it, the system will read X:\Program Files as C:\Program Files, while the actual files are in X, this is the safest way to do it, and you don't have to change anything in the system at all (including the registry).

All you need to do is to Move the Programs File to the other drive and then open the command prompt as Administrator. Now type `mklink /d C:\Program Files X:\Program Files` then hit Enter, and you're done ;) .. 
Just remember to Change the X to your drive letter.

Do the same process to the Program Files (x86) folder.

If you want everything back as it was, you just need to delete the link that you created.

That's it ..

Comment: Funny enough you get a syntax error, this is because it expects a path without a space in it. so "Program Files" is not a valid syntax. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: After some research I figured this is how to do it

1. Go to your root directory and type: dir /x.     
2. Then it will return the arbitrary directory name, in this case PROGRA~1.

Comment: If you add quotes to the paths it'll solve the space problem, so you have to quote the path like "C:\Program Files" "X:\Program Files", and it'll work fine. (I didn't mention that because I rarely use quotes, and I totally forgot about it).