# Can I run a Windows XP 32 bit programm on a Windows 7 64 bit processor

Tags: virtualbox, 64-bit, virtual-machine, 32-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Install and run 32 bit on 64 bit machine](https://superuser.com/questions/194378/install-and-run-32-bit-on-64-bit-machine)

64-bit 32-bit virtualbox virtual machine

Comment: Your question is extremely confusing - what exactly are you asking here? Are you trying to 32-bit Windows XP in a VM running on Windows 7 64-bit?

Answer (score 2):

If the machine is 64bit, the VM windows doesn't have to be to run 64bit programs. Any 64bit OS can run 32bit programs, but 64bit windows can't run 32bit drivers.

Please provide more detailed questions, in full sentences in the future.