# Quake 3 won't install on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Install and run 32 bit on 64 bit machine](https://superuser.com/questions/194378/install-and-run-32-bit-on-64-bit-machine)

Today I tried to install Quake 3 from my original 1999 CD on a Windows 7 laptop. Windows 7 resolutely refused to run the installer, helpfully explaining that I might need a 32- or 64-bit version, depending on what my OS is (you have to love those Windows error messages: absolutely correct, but as unhelpful as humanly possible).

In any case, of course the 1999 software is 32-bit, and the laptop is 64-bit. But I was pretty sure that 64-bit Windows versions could handle running 32-bit software. What gives?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [this Facepunch thread](http://facepunch.com/threads/1096741), the Quake III CD comes with a 16-bit "Autorun" launcher. (Windows refuses to run it since 64-bit x86_64 does not support running 16-bit code natively.) However, you can bypass the launcher and run `DEMO32.EXE` directly, which contains the actual installation program; when prompted for a file, give it `QIII.DBD`.

> **Method 1: If you MUST have a classic QIII/Q3TA installation**
>
> Instead of launching SETUP.EXE, just run DEMO32.EXE and a file open dialog should appear. Point it to QIII.DBD on the CD.
>
> [...]
>
> Remember to apply the 1.32 point release AFTER installing both Q3A and Q3TA. The official 1.32 point release is available from the official ID Software site - www.idsoftware.com
>
> **Method 2: Using ioQuake3**
>
> There is an engine update called ioQuake3. It's less buggy and more efficient than classic Q3 1.32
>
> Install ioQuake3 first (http://ioquake3.org/get-it/) and then from the same page, grab the data installer as well. It will unpack your CD for you.
>
> *[(KD007 on Facepunch)](http://facepunch.com/threads/1096741)*

In the earlier days of 32-bit Windows, many 32-bit programs would come with 16-bit installers (especially InstallShield) or at least having an initial 16-bit stage; one *possible* reason for this was to display a proper explanation message when the user attempted to install the program in Windows 3.x.

Comment: Excellent, that works flawlessly. I note with some amusement that the error message *could* have said that `setup.exe` was 16-bit, but did not explicitly mention it.

Comment: Note that for a very limited list of 16-bit installer technologies (the cases where it was legally and technically feasible, and where the effort was deemed essential for backwards compatibility), Windows has on-the-fly replacement programs that will silently run in place of the actual 16-bit installer. These proxy programs know about the internal format used by the installer and can do the installation on their behalf. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384143(v=vs.85).aspx.